# Like Remember The Milk, but Maintained

Tags: linux, web-apps, project-management, note-taking

I've tried several times to move my personal organization system to Remember the Milk, because it has rich support for three features I really like:

- **keyboard**: just about every field has a keyboard shortcut, which makes entry and maintenance very efficient
- **tags**: clearly visible, clickable, and there's a separate management screen
- **searches**: mix and match most attributes, boolean operators, and save favorite searches

Unfortunately, the web-app has been all but abandoned, going without even bug fixes. Is there another application that has these features, either on Linux (perfect!) or the web (acceptable)?

[EDITED TO ADD]: Web-app recommendations also need to include two-factor authentication that doesn't require a smartphone. I apologize for not including this in the original post, but it didn't occur to me that this would still be an issue in mid-2015. :/

Comment: I just saw your edit and updated my answer. Please leave a comment on the answers whenever you add essential information to your post so that other users will have a chance to update theirs

Comment: Because it wasn't requested in the original post. And since StackExchange doesn't notify the answerer whenever the question changes, the asker should do it manually by comments, or post a follow-up question if the feature is important enough

Answer (score 1):

### [Todoist](https://todoist.com)

I use Todoist as a personal organization and project management tool. It is free to try, but most features require a premium subscription. It supports your requirements as well as many other features:

- [**Keyboard shortcuts**](https://todoist.com/Help/KeyboardShortcuts) for entries, editing, formatting, and search
- **Tags**, referred to as [**labels**](https://todoist.com/Help/Labels). Visible, clickable, and with customizable color coding
- **Searches**, called [**Filters**](https://todoist.com/Help/Filtering) accepts natural language for dates, mixing of project and label attributes, and use of boolean operators

Todoist does not currently have a Linux app, but it has web apps, as well as Chrome and Firefox extensions. Here's the current list of supported platforms:

[image]

---

**Edit re 2-factor authentication**

While still not natively supported in Todoist, you can use two-factor authentication by activating it in Google then logging in using your Google account

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### [Toodledo](http://toodledo.com/)

I was using Remember the Milk my self a little on and off, even had a premium subscription for a year. Today I'm using [Toodledo](http://toodledo.com/) and it seems to fullfil most of my needs, and according to your current list most of yours.

- The main screen displays most [keyboard shortcuts](http://www.toodledo.com/info/help.php#18), but you can press `?` and get all of them in a popup window
- It has [tags](http://www.toodledo.com/info/help.php#8), and a separate organize tags window
- And it has a rather powerful [search enginge](http://www.toodledo.com/info/search.php) with the possibility to save searches, and it also supports filters

In addition to being a good task organizer, Toodle do also has both outlines, notes, lists and habits. All areas I like to have joined in one tool. And you can customise the fields of the tasks to your likeing, and can choose from fields such as: *Folder, Context, Goal, Start Date, Start Time, Due Date, Due Time, Repeat, Length, Timer, Priority, Tag, Status, Star, Location, Assignor, Trashcan*.

I also like the fact that multiple apps (for both ios and android), browser plugins and desktop applications are using the toodledo api, meaning that you can choose from a variety of access point to access your toodledo account.

The free version is [fully functional](http://www.toodledo.com/subscribe/index.php), albeit limited in the number of lists and stuff, but *there is no such thing as a free lunch*. And there seems to be an active community around Toodledo, both the main developers and developers for 3rd party applications.

Answer (score 0):

I find the Nirvana web app (and iPhone app) really good, with great support for keyboard and tags

https://www.nirvanahq.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source [Nitro](https://github.com/CaffeinatedCode/nitro) service, which provides a slick interface, lists, tags, keyboard shortcuts and search. It has a web version, Linux and mobile apps.

Alternatively, you can use a closed source [Wunderlist](http://wunderlist.com/).